# how to describe this regular expression in English

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I am trying to describe regular expression in English here,

and let's say we have for `(b(bb)*)*`

you would say: `zero or more b's`

or we can have `(a(aa)*b(bb)*)*`

you would say: `odd number of a's that end in odd number of b's`

now my question is about `((a+b)a)*`

you would say: `words of even length where every even letter is an 'a'`

where did the even length come from ??? how did they get every even letter is an 'a' ? is it from the zero a's because zero is an even number ?

Comment: It doesn't match only words of even length consider "aba" or "aaaba"

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting these descriptions, but they are wrong. `(b(bb)*)*` matches zero or an odd number of b's. `(a(aa)*b(bb)*)*` matches what you described, but also the empty string. `((a+b)a)*` does not require that the word be even length or that every even letter be an `a`. `foo` and `fooaaba` also match.

Comment: Where do those descriptions come from? They don't seem very accurate.

Comment: Can't `(b(bb)*)*` match an even number of b's?

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for correcting me , this is exactly what I wrote and I got marked wrong for using 'odd'!

Comment: @pandubear  Yes: Valids are, starting at nothing: "", `b`, `bbb`, `bbbb` (`bbb` from first iteration, `b` from second), ...

Comment: @Ris I'd recommend you use a tool like https://www.debuggex.com/ to test out these regexes. (Not my tool, no affiliation; I just like it.) The descriptions above are no good. Sorry you got marked down for a good answer!

Comment: @EdCottrell thank you..this is very useful..I never heard of this

Comment: @pandubear You're right, `(b(bb)*)*` could match an even number. I was wrong on that one. Oops!

Comment: (b(bb)*)* is essentially the same as b*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((a+b)a)*
```

*"you would say: words of even length where every even letter is an 'a'"*

This is not a correct description. More accurate would be "words that have *at least one `a`*, followed by *exactly one `b`*, followed by *exactly one `a`*, zero or more times"

(`+` means "one or more", `*` means "zero or more".)

It's more about the back and forth of `a`s and `b`s--there could be million `a`s between the `b`s, but there's never two `b`s next to each other.

And note that the inner parenthesis are not needed. In other words, this is equivalent:

```
(a+ba)*
```

---

Free spaced:

```
(a+     //"a", one or more times
 b      //followed by exactly one "b"
 a      //followed by exactly one "a"
)*      //zero or more times
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how did you get ab in there ? sorry I am new to this...isn't that saying a or b ?

Comment: never mind you edited the answer...now I finally got it..thank you so much for taking the time

Comment: Looking at the comment at Judge Mental's answer, this answer is incorrect, since the "+" sign should be interpreted as "or", as is usually done in formal language classes.

Answer (score 3):

The only way your description is accurate is if you interpret the expression `a+b` as `a` or `b`.  Most regular expression tools write this using a vertical bar, as in `a|b`.  The other commenters and answerers have interpreted the + as a postfix operator meaning "one or more".

Using that reading, the reason every string in this set must be of even length is because the repetition comes outside a string of length 2.  It means "zero or more copies of either aa or ba".  Clearly every word matching that description is of even length.  0 is even by definition, and every second letter has to be an `a`.

{ ¢, aa, ba, aaaa, aaba, baaa, baba, ... }

Comment: I did interpret the expression a+b as a or b

Comment: If you consider the "+" to be an or (which I suppose is the case, since I suspect you're doing a class in formal language), then this should be the correct answer, you should change your accepted answer. And the descriptions you give are all correct, except the second one, where it should be added that the string you have described can be repeated 0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

OP, your question is based on curriculum from lecture and text where + is intended as an OR operation. The text and lecture material makes very clear what the notation means...

`(b(bb)*)*` = 0-n b's followed by 0-n bb's. in other words, zero or more b's.

`(a(aa)*b(bb)*)*` follows the pattern 2n + 1 a's following with 2n + 1 b's, if 
                  not an empty string.

`((a+b)a)*` is more ambiguous i.e. more things could be said about it than the 
            answer, but the answer cannot be said to be wrong either. It is all 
            words of even length composed of all a's, or a's and b's. My guess 
            is that this answer would have gotten partial credit, and full 
            credit for including the part about a's being the even letter.